# laravel yajratable - hide column but make it searchable

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

i have the following code:

**view-table:**

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center" style="padding:0px; margin-left: -58px">
    <table id="all" class="table table-bordered yajra-datatable">
        <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Team</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>CC</th>
            <th>Skills</th>
            <th>Team</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
            public function getEmployees_all()
        {

           $data = DB::table('employees')->select('first_name', 'last_name','email','name_abb_mappings.cc','name_abb_mappings.team', 'skills', 'file')
               ->leftJoin('name_abb_mappings','employees.abbreviation','=','name_abb_mappings.id')
               ->get();

            $data11 = Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('download', function ($data) {
                    return ' <form action="'.route('download').'" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> '.@csrf_field().'  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" style="color:orangered" name="downloadProfile" value= "'.$data->file.'">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-file-pdf" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M4 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h8a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H4zm0 1h8a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H4a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1z"></path>
                <path d="M4.603 12.087a.81.81 0 0 1-.438-.42c-.195-.388-.13-.776.08-1.102.198-.307.526-.568.897-.787a7.68 7.68 0 0 1 1.482-.645 19.701 19.701 0 0 0 1.062-2.227 7.269 7.269 0 0 1-.43-1.295c-.086-.4-.119-.796-.046-1.136.075-.354.274-.672.65-.823.192-.077.4-.12.602-.077a.7.7 0 0 1 .477.365c.088.164.12.356.127.538.007.187-.012.395-.047.614-.084.51-.27 1.134-.52 1.794a10.954 10.954 0 0 0 .98 1.686 5.753 5.753 0 0 1 1.334.05c.364.065.734.195.96.465.12.144.193.32.2.518.007.192-.047.382-.138.563a1.04 1.04 0 0 1-.354.416.856.856 0 0 1-.51.138c-.331-.014-.654-.196-.933-.417a5.716 5.716 0 0 1-.911-.95 11.642 11.642 0 0 0-1.997.406 11.311 11.311 0 0 1-1.021 1.51c-.29.35-.608.655-.926.787a.793.793 0 0 1-.58.029zm1.379-1.901c-.166.076-.32.156-.459.238-.328.194-.541.383-.647.547-.094.145-.096.25-.04.361.01.022.02.036.026.044a.27.27 0 0 0 .035-.012c.137-.056.355-.235.635-.572a8.18 8.18 0 0 0 .45-.606zm1.64-1.33a12.647 12.647 0 0 1 1.01-.193 11.666 11.666 0 0 1-.51-.858 20.741 20.741 0 0 1-.5 1.05zm2.446.45c.15.162.296.3.435.41.24.19.407.253.498.256a.107.107 0 0 0 .07-.015.307.307 0 0 0 .094-.125.436.436 0 0 0 .059-.2.095.095 0 0 0-.026-.063c-.052-.062-.2-.152-.518-.209a3.881 3.881 0 0 0-.612-.053zM8.078 5.8a6.7 6.7 0 0 0 .2-.828c.031-.188.043-.343.038-.465a.613.613 0 0 0-.032-.198.517.517 0 0 0-.145.04c-.087.035-.158.106-.196.283-.04.192-.03.469.046.822.024.111.054.227.09.346z"></path>
                </svg>
              </button>
              </form>';

                })

                ->rawColumns(['download'])
                ->make(true);

            return $data11;
}
```

**Route**

```
   Route::GET('employee/all', [EmployeeController::class, 'getEmployees_all'])->name('employees.all');
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function () {
   var table = $('#all').DataTable({
        order: [[1, "desc"]],
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
         ajax: "{{route('employees.all') }}",
        columns: [

            {data: 'first_name', name: 'first_name'},
            {data: 'last_name', name: 'last_name'},
            {data: 'team', name: 'team'},
            {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
            {data: 'cc', name: 'cc'},
            {data: 'skills', name: 'skills'},
            {data: 'team', name: 'team'},

            {
                data: 'download',
                name: 'download',
                orderable: true,
                searchable: true
            },


        ]
    });
});
```

So far the table is working.

My problem:

I need to make the column "Skills" hidden but searchable within the datatable search box.
If i just hide the column wih css like `display:none` then the table gets broken in terms of
the columns get shifted to the left somehow and the entries are in the wrong columns.
However its not working that way. Is there any other way to do that. I hope i could explain it properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not particularly complicated :

```
{data: 'skills', name: 'skills', searchable : true, visible: false},
```

will hide the column but leave it searchable.

Comment: For some reason, in my case the visible: false seems to be totally ignored