# Laravel Datatables - Searchable hidden column still requires a table header column?

Tags: datatables, laravel-9

I have a Laravel index page with yajra datatables of a model of a customer, with tags (one-to-many) flattened into a single column. This all works as expected. Here is my javascript from my `index.blade.php`

```
@push('child-scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
    lengthMenu: [ 10, 25, 50, 75, 100 ],
    pageLength: 50,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: "{{ route('customer.index') }}",
    columns: [
        {data: 'title', name: 'title'},
        {data: 'field', name: 'field'},
        {data: 'people_count', name: 'people_count', searchable: false},
        {data: 'contact_count', name: 'contact_count', searchable: false},
        {data: 'phone_count', name: 'phone_count', searchable: false},
        {data: 'sample', name: 'sample'},
        {data: 'tags', name: 'tags'},
        {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
        ]});
  });
</script>
```

here is the relevent part of my html from the same file

```
<table class="table data-table table-auto strange">
    <thead class="border-b">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Field</th>
            <th>
                <x-fluentui-people-16-o /></th>
            <th>
                <x-fluentui-contact-card-16-o  /></th>
            <th>
                <x-fluentui-call-16-o /></th>
            <th>Sample</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The tags are verbose and taking too much screen real estate. [image]

I followed the directions here to make them searchable but not visible.
[laravel yajratable - hide column but make it searchable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70151861/laravel-yajratable-hide-column-but-make-it-searchable)

```
{data: 'tags', name: 'tags', visible: false},
```

Adding `visible: false` did the trick, I can search for tags and get results.

[image]

### Question

All of this breaks, the moment I remove ` <th></th> ` from the html. I must have 8 `<th>` elements even though I only have 7 visible columns. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is a little embarrassing. I went back to add titles to my header columns to make them a little more clear.

```
            <th>Sample</th>
            <th>Tags</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Only to discover that the Tag header cell for the corresponding column was gone; datatables had hidden it too. I left it off it off because I presumed that it would just get in the way. I have wasted so much time on this already, but I hope this will be a help to someone else.

### TL;DR

Datatables proactively removes the header cell for the corresponding column; you must add it so datatables can hide it.

[image]